# Is there a way to read the calcuated value in excel using openpyxl without data_only = True?

Tags: python, openpyxl

When I use `data_only = True`, it gets rid of all of the formulas and I don't want that. I just want it to be able to reference the actual calculated value and then do stuff with it. Then I want to be able to go back into the spreadsheet and have it work as it did before.

The only solution I can think of is to basically have python execute the command that excel does, but I don't even know if that's possible. For example if on Sheet1, cell `A5 = "Sheet1!A1^2"`, would it be possible or practical to ask python to go into Sheet1A1 and grab the value from it?

I tried using `data_only = True` and it ruined my spreadsheet as it got rid of all the relationships between the cells.

Comment: Try cell value with '=' prefix in the formula; e.g. `=Sheet1!A1^2`. If formula works in Excel then `data_only = true` will evaluate the formula and return the value.

Comment: As mentioned in the documentation, this is by design. But you can easily open the workbook twice, once in read-only, data-only mode, and once normally.

Comment: Would it be possible have the same workbook but assigned to two variables where one is ```data_only = False``` and the other is ```data_only = True```? Then I'd only save the ```data_only = False``` workbook?

Comment: Would it be possible have the same workbook but assigned to two variables where one is ```data_only = False``` and the other is ```data_only = True```? Then I'd only save the ```data_only = False``` workbook?

Answer (score 0):

So what I did is I opened the same workbook twice. Once as `data_only = True` the other as `data_only = False`. I only then saved the workbook that was `data_only = False`. That seemed to work.

Here's the relevant code:

```
import os, os.path
import openpyxl
import glob
Files = glob.glob('./*.csv')
directory_path = os.getcwd()
file_location = directory_path

file_name1 = "Navigator.xlsx"
path1 = file_location + "\\" + file_name1

wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path1, data_only = False)
wbd = openpyxl.load_workbook(path1, data_only = True)

Worksheet1_Name = "NavLog"
Worksheet2_Name = "Departure-Arrival"

ws = wb[Worksheet1_Name]
wsd = wbd[Worksheet1_Name]

#Do whatever it is you want to do here

wb.save(file_name1)
```